# recaptcha unlock event is not passed to parent

Tags: lightning-web-components, recaptcha

We are implementing recaptcha for LWC.

We put html into static resource

```
<html>
<head>
<title>reCAPTCHA: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var verifyCallback = function (response) {
parent.postMessage("unlock", location.origin);
｝；
var onloadCallback = function) ‹
grecaptcha. render ('html_element', {
'sitekey' : 'our site key',
'callback' : verifyCallback,
｝：
</script>
</head> <body>
<form action="?" method="POST">
<div id="html_element"></div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display: none"/>
</form>
«script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async="" defer="">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

We created an LWC component

```
<template>
<iframe src=[navigateTo} name="captchaFrame" onload={captchaLoaded}
style="width: -webkit-fill-available;"> </iframe> </template>
```

with javascript

```
import & LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import pageUrl from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/recaptchaV2';
import RECAPTCHA_CHANNEL from '@salesforce/messageChannel/RecaptchaMessageChannel_c';
import { MessageContext, publish} from 'lightning/messageService';
import default class Recaptcha extends LightningElement {
@track navigateTo;
@wire (MessageContext) messageContext;
connectedCallback() l
//super () ;
this. navigateTo = pagerl;
window. addEventListener ("message", this. listenForMessage);
captchaLoaded (event)
/*let src = event. target getAttribute('src');
console. log('src = ' + src);
if (event. target getAttribute('src') == pageUrl){
console. log ( 'Google reCAPTCHA is loaded.');
｝*/
this.dispatchEvent (new CustomEvent ('loaded' ));
listenForMessage (message) {
if (message.data === 'unlock') {
console. log ('Recaptcha unlock');
//console. log( 'this messageContext = ' + this.messageContext) ;
//this.sendMessageService();
//console. log ('messageContext published out!');
this.dispatchEvent (new CustomEvent( 'unlocked', (bubbles: true, composed: true}));
debugger;
console. log( 'dispatchEvent done!');
}
```

and with a parent component

```
<div if:true={guestUser} class="slds-m-top_small">
<c-recaptcha onunlocked={handleCaptcha} onloaded={handleCaptchaLoaded}>/c-recaptcha>
<div if:true={noCAPTCHA} class="error-style">
CAPTCHA verification is required.
</div>
</div>

handleCaptcha() {
debugger;
console. log( 'handleCaptcha unlocked1');
this. captcha = true;
console. log( 'handleCaptcha unlocked');
}
handleCaptchaLoaded () {
console. log( 'handleCaptcha loaded');
}
```

We are very confused since `loaded` event is passed from the child component to the parent, but the `unlocked` event is not passed.

Why it is not working? Why it is working for one event but not for the another one?

Message channel doesn't work either.